# Capturing frames from an h264 stream with gst/ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264

I want to save (as jpegs) or reach the data of the frames streaming from my usb camera.
Meaning that I want to use the h.264 hardware encoding (I running it on nvdia jetson) in order to get a sequence of compressed files (I prefer not save it on the disc and get an array, if possible).
Can I do that?

So far I tried this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! decodebin ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=img_%04d.jpg
```

but I get an internal data flow error from v4l2src0 element, and an error from gst_base_src_loop() after the pipeline was set to PLAYING.

Can anybody please help me?

b.t.w- It doesnt have to be neccecerly h.264 encoding, it also can be mpeg encoding or something else: I want to use the fact that it is pictures of a video, frames, in order to get smaller size frames.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you check if the video from the camera works by trying gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! fakesink

Comment: Yes it works perfectly

Comment: Similarly can you try to add the fakesink till this point: gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! decodebin ! fakesink ? - basically just identify the plugin which causes it to return the error. Keep progressing the fakesink along the filters so we can better understand what is going on.

Comment: It stopped working on this filter..
"gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,framera‌​te=30/1,stream-format‌​=byte-stream ! decodebin ! fakesink"
returned an error

Comment: Instead of the decodebin can you add h264parse filter and then the omxh264dec filter and fakesink them. Do this one step at a time h264parse ! fakesink and then h264parse ! omxh264dec ! fakesink. You need to be sure you have omxh264dec by checking it with gst-inspect.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please write the whole line?

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! fakesink - does this work?